Newman failure reason details gets truncated in HTML report
In my newman HTML report, I have an assertion error, which cannot be completely readable because the details gets truncated.
This issue occurs when I have updated newman, node.js and html reportextra to latest version.
FYI, this issue not reproduced when I downgrade the newman version to 5.3.2
Steps:

I'm using Latest Newman Version in Windows machine
Executing the postman collection thru newman command with HTML report extra


